# Cycle dependency Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I receive error message "Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  jpaProductsDaoImpl defined in file [C:\W#####\Repository_IntelliJ\A####\out\production\classes\pl\edu\agh\bazydanych2017\dao\jpa\JpaProductsDaoImpl.class]"
└─────┘

**JpaProductsDaoImpl class**

```
@Repository
public class JpaProductsDaoImpl {

    private final JpaProductsDao jpaProductsDao;

    @Autowired
    public JpaProductsDaoImpl(JpaProductsDao jpaProductsDao) {
        this.jpaProductsDao = jpaProductsDao;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void jpaRunAtStart(){
        Products findByName = jpaProductsDao.findByProductname("Chai");
        System.out.println("JPA " + findByName);

        List<Products> sortByProductName = jpaProductsDao.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "productname"));
        for (Products products : sortByProductName) {
            System.out.println("JPA Sort " + products);
        }

    }
```

- Can You tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What are the other components which are part of the cycle? Please show the full error message.

Comment: You are injecting a bean into itself in the constructor...